# Is it possible to map a column name in an Laravel Eloquent model?

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a DB table with a column "visible" (true/false).

The Eloquent model already has a property visible, see this code snippet taken from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be visible in arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $visible = array();
```

When printing out the model, the "visible" property is the already existing array instead of the column value. Is there a way to rename the column in the Model? I already tried this (found here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

```
public function setVisibleAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['isvisible'] = $value;
}
public function getVisibleAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['isvisible'];
}
```

I know I can solve the problem like this:

```
User::select('id', 'name', 'visible as isVisible')->get();
```

I was just wondering if there  isn't a really built in mechanism.

Important note: the DB is also used by existing software so renaming it isn't really an option.

Comment: Accessors and mutators aren't the answer here because they are triggered from __get in Model and this function isn't called since getVisible is an existing function.

Comment: `getVisible` is an existing function? Where?

Comment: I just did a quick test and just using `->visible` worked without a problem. This is due the fact that the visible array is protected!

Comment: It seems getVisible isn't a function indeed.

I have some custom generic code to map a model to an array so the problem must be in there since I always got an array in the "visible" property instead of the boolean value.

Anyway, I changed the column name to "isvisible" and adapted the other applications using this database, it wasn't much work after all. So my problem is solved.

Comment: Alright. Add that code to the question and I'll see if I can spot something.